# MonoGame - ScissorRectangle not working

Tags: c#, monogame

I'm trying to create a scrollable log window with RenderTarget2D and ScissorRectangle. The ScissorRectangle, however, does not seem to work. Here's the code:

```
spriteBatch.End();

spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, null, null, null, new RasterizerState() { ScissorTestEnable = true });

Rectangle scissor = new Rectangle(0, Constants.GAME_AREA_HEIGHT, Constants.GAME_AREA_WIDTH, Constants.LOG_HEIGHT);
Rectangle scissorBackup = this.graphicsDevice.ScissorRectangle;
this.graphicsDevice.ScissorRectangle = scissor;

spriteBatch.Draw(logRenderTarget,
    new Rectangle(0, Constants.GAME_AREA_HEIGHT, Constants.GAME_AREA_WIDTH, Constants.LOG_HEIGHT),
    Color.White
);

this.graphicsDevice.ScissorRectangle = scissorBackup;

spriteBatch.End();

spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure root of the problem is that the scissor rectangle is *only* applied during the `SpriteBatch.End` call. So in the code above, you're resetting it too early.

Comment: I've  found that setting up the `RasterizerState` on the `spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice` before `spriteBatch.Begin` AND passing it into `spriteBatch.Begin` are both necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to switch to using a Viewport. It seems, however, that MonoGame uses the last set-up Viewport before the call to `spriteBatch.End()`. It also seems that it is the same with the ScissorRectangle, so I could have made it also work. I have added the ScissorRectangle-specific code here in comments. Here's my new class:

```
public class LogWriter
{
    private GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice;

    private Viewport defaultViewport, logViewport;
    //private Rectangle scissor, scissorBackup;

    public void Init(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice)
    {
        this.graphicsDevice = graphicsDevice;

        defaultViewport = this.graphicsDevice.Viewport;
        logViewport = new Viewport(0, Constants.GAME_AREA_HEIGHT, Constants.GAME_AREA_WIDTH, Constants.LOG_HEIGHT);

        //scissor = new Rectangle(0, Constants.GAME_AREA_HEIGHT, Constants.GAME_AREA_WIDTH, Constants.LOG_HEIGHT);
        //scissorBackup = this.graphicsDevice.ScissorRectangle;
    }

    public void WriteLog(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        this.graphicsDevice.Viewport = logViewport;
        //this.graphicsDevice.ScissorRectangle = scissor;

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        //spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, null, null, null, new RasterizerState() { ScissorTestEnable = true });

        for (int i = 0; i < Log.Count; i++)
        {
            spriteBatch.DrawString(Scavenger.AssetManager.Font12,
                Log.Entries[i],
                new Vector2(
                    Constants.LOG_MARGIN,
                    Constants.LOG_MARGIN + i * Scavenger.AssetManager.Font12.LineSpacing),
                Color.GreenYellow
            );
        }

        spriteBatch.End();

        this.graphicsDevice.Viewport = defaultViewport;
        //this.graphicsDevice.ScissorRectangle = scissorBackup;
    }
}
```

`Init()` is called in the `LoadContent()` function. `WriteLog()` is called in the `Draw()` function after `End()` has been called on the spriteBatch after drawing all the other things.